# SQL return data related to the corresponding MAX() value

Tags: sql, ms-access, max

I´ve a problem with a SQL query. My database look like this:

```
State   | City         | Population
-----------------------------------
Texas   | Austin       | 865.00
Texas   | Houston      | 2.200.00
Florida | Jacksonville | 840.000
Florida | Miami        | 417.000
...     | ...          | ...
```

Now i want to know the maximum population of a state and the related city like this:

```
OUTPUT:
 State   | City         | Population
 -----------------------------------
 Texas   | Houston      | 2.200.00
 Florida | Jacksonville | 840.000
 ...     | ...          | ...
```

How can i do this?

EDIT: I use MSAcces 2013, Table name: TPopulation. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Which rdbms you use?

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri MSAcces

Comment: Hi, @Cryxon! Notice that you will get a lot of "T" or "MyTable" stuff if you don't supply table schema information. So, it's up to you to make use of that for your exact setup (correct table names, etc.) Help us out - edit your post to include exact table and column names. The right answer will come out.

Comment: @ Pittsburgh DBAThx, I updated my post in order to avoid inconsistencies

Comment: OK. I updated my answer. Note that @shawnt00 answer is correct. You simply need to change "T" to "TPopulation" in the FROM clauses. If this does not work for you, then you have a mistake somewhere, either in column names or in your typing.

Answer (score 2):

This method allows for ties although those are pretty unlikely here.

```
-- overall
select t1.State, t1.City, t1.Population
from T as t1
where Population = (
    select max(t2.Population) from T as t2
)

-- per state
select t1.State, t1.City, t1.Population
from T as t1
where t1.Population = (
    select max(t2.Population) from T as t2 where t2.State = t1.State
)
```

Comment: Since @cryxon has said now that he is using MSAccess, I prefer your 2nd query versus my own.

Comment: If i try the second one, acces asked for data.

Comment: @Cryxon the query needs full name qualification via the aliases. Try this. It may also be a case of incorrect table or column names. select t1.State, t1.City, t1.Population from T as t1 where t1.Population = ( select max(t2.Population) from T as t2 where t2.State = t1.State )

Answer (score 0):

Note that this will return multiple cities per state, if the max population is the same for more than one city per state.

MS ACCESS:

```
SELECT 
  T1.State,
  T1.City,
  T1.Population
FROM
  TPopulation AS T1
WHERE
  T1.Population =
    (SELECT MAX(T2.Population) FROM TPopulation AS T2 WHERE T2.State = T1.State)
```

ANSI:

```
SELECT
    MaxP.State,
    S.City,
    S.Population
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        State,
        MAX(Population)
    FROM
        TPopulation
    GROUP BY
        State
    ) AS MaxP
    INNER JOIN TPopulation AS S ON
        S.State = MaxP.State
        AND S.Population = MaxP.Population
ORDER BY
    MaxP.State ASC,
    S.City ASC
```

Comment: I start to understand which question you understand from the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. It shows the right order, the biggest city first in each state. But it shows every city in each state and I only want the biggest city in each state:

```
SELECT State, City, Population
FROM TPopulation
ORDER BY State DESC , Population DESC;

OUTPUT:
State   | City         | Population
-----------------------------------
Texas   | Houston      | 2.200.00
Texas   | Austin       | 865.00
Florida | Jacksonville | 840.000
Florida | Miami        | 417.000
...     | ...          | ...
```